# VPN server stopped functioning with Windows clients

Tags: vpn, rras

Our Windows 2003R2 VPN server (Routing and Remote access) no longer lets Windows clients (Windows 7, with the latest MS patches) connect.

The client tries, and craps out with Error 806. This is PPTP.

Thing is: It worked just fine until 1-2 days ago, apparently.
No patches have been applied to the server since then, no changes on either firewall (client nor server).

When I try with the built-in VPN client on my Android phone, I am able to connect successfully (via 3G).

I'm just not sure where to look further... I'll try the phone on the same network as the client in a bit, and I'll bring along another laptop to test with, but it just doesn't make sense...  :-/

Comment: 806 is usually related to allowing GRE (IP 47) traffic through.  If nothing has changed though, try restarting the RRAS service.  If that doesn't work, can you debug the firewall logs and see if the traffic is still traversing correctly?  -- Oh and I'm sure you've heard it before but you should consider ditching the PPTP VPN for something more secure and authenticates at the edge instead of the server level.

Comment: It could indeed be firewall related, although a restart of the firewall didn't help.
Now that I'm at home I've tried my Android phone via Wifi: no-go. It still connects via 3G though. That would suggest the problem is in the firewall on the client-side, right?

Comment: OK, but do the firewalls allow for debug logging of the sessions?  With your phone working fine, it makes me wonder why the clients suddenly cannot connect.  And yeah, if you're at home on wifi and it suddenly won't connect I would suspect the home router but most allow anything outbound by default.